# Firebase Functions emails with images where to store

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I want to send emails to my customers with firebase functions. In this emails I would like to display my logo but where do I need to put my image file (company_logo.png) so that I can use it in my function later and how do I access the image file?

I currently have my logo image (.png) directly in the firebase functions folder but for sure this does not work...

Please find a snippet of my code below

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet'>
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: 'Poppins';
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:#EEEEEE;font-size:20px;color:black;">
        <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:3em;margin-bottom:3em;">
            <img src="company_logo.png" alt="company logo" style="width:200px;height:52px;">
        </div>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your image on a storage bucket and [grant public read access to the image](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public). After that, access your image [by using an API link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data#api-link) as it does not require authentication. For example:

```
<img src="https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/company_logo.png" alt="company logo" style="width:200px;height:52px;">
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. I created a new bucket in firebase storage and uploadad the pictures. I got the link for the pictures directly from the bucket (clock on the picture). Work perfectly fine. Thanks!!